# Subscript out of range at: Debug.Print arr(i, 1)

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to iterate through an array using:-

```
For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
    Debug.Print arr(i, 1)
Next i
```

but receive a Subscript out of range error at `Debug.Print arr(i, 1)` which I do not understand. The code works fine if I take out the above lines.

```
Sub Summarise()
    Dim dict
    Dim i As Long
    Dim arr() As Variant
    Dim n As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet

    Set ws2 = Worksheets("Plan")
    Set ws = Worksheets("Data")
    dict = ws.[A1].CurrentRegion.Value
    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        For i = 1 To UBound(dict, 1)
            .Item(dict(i, 1)) = .Item(dict(i, 1)) + dict(i, 5)
        Next
        arr = Array(.Keys, .items)
        n = .Count
    End With

    For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        Debug.Print arr(i, 1)
    Next i

    ws2.[A1].CurrentRegion.ClearContents
    ws2.[A1].Resize(n, 2).Value = Application.Transpose(arr)   
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your line `arr = Array(.Keys, .items)` is creating an array of arrays and not an array of those items.

i.e. `Array(Array(1,2,3), Array(4,5,6))`

To loop through this you would need to do something like

```
For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
    For j = LBound(arr(i)) to UBound(arr(i))
        Debug.Print arr(i)(j)
    Next j
Next i
```

To avoid doing this and loop through as you're currently you could add to your array as you add to your dictionary